# Reload page at current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a page which width is 600vw. 
It works kinda like a slide show but then with pages.

The problem is that I don't want my page to refresh and load at the first position but at the current position.
I read some things about how to do it with `ScrollTop()` and I also tried chancing every `ScrollTop()` to a `ScrollLeft()` but that doesn't work. **see code:**

```
var page_y = $( document ).ScrollLeft();
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?page_y=' + page_y;


//code to handle setting page offset on load
$(function() {
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf( 'page_y' ) != -1 ) {
        //gets the number from end of url
        var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].match( /\d+$/ );
        var page_y = match[0];

        //sets the page offset 
        $( 'html, body' ).ScrollLeft( page_y );
    }
});
```

also `document.location.reload(true)` doesn't work, when I refresh with that in my code it just gives a

> 502 Bad Gateway

I want to use php or jquery/ javascript.

Current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            $('button.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
        $('#slide1').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "0";
        });
        $('#slide2').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "-500px";
        });
        $('#slide3').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "-1000px";
        });
 });
```

```css
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
    width: 500px;
}

nav button{
    width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

article {
    width: 1500px;
    position: absolute;
}

.page{
    width: 490px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
         <ul>
            <button id="slide1"><li>slide1</li></button>
            <button id="slide2"><li>slide2</li></button>
            <button id="slide3"><li>slide3</li></button>
         </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article id='article'>
<div class='page' style='background-color: green;'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: red;'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: yellow;'></div>
</article>
```

if I add

```
var page_y = $( document ).scrollLeft();

//code to handle setting page offset on load
$(function() {
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf( 'page_y' ) != -1 ) {
        //gets the number from end of url
        var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].match( /\d+$/ );
        var temp_page_y = match[0];

        //sets the page offset 
        $( 'html, body' ).scrollLeft( temp_page_y );
    } else {
        /****** the code *****/
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '?page_y=' + page_y;
    }
});
```

the code doesn't work

Comment: What is `dia` ?

Comment: Who is this **dia**?

Comment: And further question since you didn't post HTML: Does the element you try scrolling on have overflow? If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow), scrollLeft is set to 0. Also - scrollLeft

Comment: German for slideshow?

Comment: Also it is `scrollLeft()` not `ScrollLeft()` which is why you have an error at the first place!

Comment: @ProEvilz  Oh sorry thought it also was an english word but noticed now that it is not. It's like a slide from a slideshow but I edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the new url with `page_y` in window.location.href on script run, thats why your page reloads every time. Please use this on `else` condition.

```
var page_y = $( document ).scrollLeft();

//code to handle setting page offset on load
$(function() {
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf( 'page_y' ) != -1 ) {
        //gets the number from end of url
        var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].match( /\d+$/ );
        var temp_page_y = match[0];

        //sets the page offset 
        $( 'html, body' ).scrollLeft( temp_page_y );
    } else {
        /****** the code *****/
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '?page_y=' + page_y;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your full html and js code in your question?

Comment: sorry, it does still move but just doesn't refresh at current position (or change anything in the link)  i'll post current code now

Comment: your code doesn't scroll because in url you have current page_y position. If you change value from url then you will see that page_y position with page reloading.

Comment: `scrollLeft()` is the right function. Please see here about [scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/), I think you can proceed with your next step. This code I didn't tested, I am just point out problem in your code.

Comment: Use Browser Developer tool for debugging your codes. You will understand how the code behaves and see the Console for errors.

Comment: Not getting any errors in the console, but at every place that I reset the page it gives back `page y=0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155756/discussion-between-miraz-chowdhury-and-minegolfer).

Comment: Chowdhurry I was in chat all the time but you left?